# Yeoman: Grunt renames files referenced by CSS

Tags: yeoman

I have the following directory structure:

```
porthole
  - server
  - client
```

Client contains an AngularJS application scaffolded by `generator-angular`.

I've modified the `Gruntfile.js` to set `yeoman.dist` to build the application into `../server/public`:

```
// Project settings
yeoman: {
  // configurable paths
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  dist: '../server/public/'
},
```

Now when I build the project, every file referenced from a CSS file (background images, fonts, etc) get rewriting with absolute paths:

For example this:

```
background: url("../../images/bg.jpg")
```

Get's translated to:

```
background: url(/Users/jviotti/Projects/porthole/client/images/bg.jpg)
```

The same happens with webfont files.

What is causing this?

**EDIT:** Gruntfile: http://pastebin.com/VxhXtMip

Answer (score 0):

OK, after looking over your Gruntfile, it looks like the issue is actually with how `cssmin` is set up. It's currently set to use `<%= yeoman.app %>` as your root regardless of which task you're running. If you remove that option it looks like it should work how you'd like.

Comment: Hi, that created a `server` directory inside `client`. I edited the post body to include a pastebin of my Gruntfile.

Comment: Are you running grunt from inside the `client` folder?